# SAS - how to select just the first out of multiple instances

Tags: sas

Hi I have the following data set:

```
Account     date
y1        01/02/2010
y1        03/02/2010
y1        04/20/2010
y2        02/02/2010
y2        03/15/2010
x2        04/15/2010
```

I just wanna select the earliest date for each account and get the following output:

```
Account     date
y1        01/02/2010
y2        02/02/2010
x2        04/15/2010
```

Thank you.

Comment: Did you do any research?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data step version: assuming that your dataset is sorted by account and date, this is a simple case of by group processing:

```
data want;
  set have;
  by account;
  if first.account;
run;
```

Comment: You need a `by` statement.

Answer (score 2):

Use proc sql, group by account, select min(date) and use the `format=` option to produce the correct date formatting:

```
proc sql;
select
  account,
  min(date) format=mmddyy10. as date
from
  yourdata
group by
  account
;
quit;
```

If you wish to store the output in a dataset, simply insert the `CREATE TABLE` clause between `PROC SQL;` and `select`:

```
proc sql;
  create table newdata as
  select
```